# Why does it only make sense to talk about roots of polynomial OVER some base field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I am fully aware I may be asking a silly question here.

But surely, polynomials with unity as coefficients is well defined over any field since every field contains 1.

So does the separability, roots change depending on the base field?

Say if I had a based field with char 0, or $p_1$, or $p_2$, what difference does it make?

thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: $x^2+1$ has one root over $\mathbb{Z}/(2)$, two over $\mathbb{C}$, no root over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: ...and no root over $\mathbb{Z}/(p)$ for $p\in\mathbb{P}\backslash\{2\}$ if $p\equiv 3(\mod 4)$ or two if $p\equiv 1(\mod 4)$

Comment: But I can certainly extend the field R to C so that it has all the roots. So can different base fields affect the properties (roots or separability of a polynomial) in their field extensions that contains roots to the same polynomial?

Comment: Exactly, and for every monic polynomial there exists (up to isomorphisms) exactly one "smallest field" over that the polynomial splits into linear factors, its splitting field

Answer (score 0):

Well to begin, every field contains some NOTION of $1$, but they will not always coincide. For instance, the $"1"$ in $Z_p$ is actually $1 + p\mathbb{Z}$.

So for polynomials in general you need a specification as to what ring its coefficients are in.

As to specifying what field the roots are in, it's still permissible to leave out what extension you are talking about; it is then understood to mean you are talking about its roots in the polynomial's splitting field.

The reason it matters in general is best seen by an example:

Consider the polynomial $x^2+1 \in \mathbb{R}[x]$. This polynomial has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$. However, it does have roots in $\mathbb{C}$, namingly $\pm i$.

This distinction matters, for instance, when you want to talk about normal extensions. An extension $E/F$ is normal if any irreducible $g \in F[x]$ having a root in $E$ splits in $E$ (all of its roots in E). So you can see in this example, the specific extension the roots are in matters. These extensions are of central interest in Galois Theory.

Comment: But I can certainly extend the field R to C so that it has all the roots. So can different base fields affect the properties (roots or separability of a polynomial) in their field extensions that contains roots to the same polynomial?

Comment: Perhaps my real question is different than what was asked. If I have two field extension K/k ,L/l, such that both K and l contain all roots to the polynomials f(x) that is in both k[x] and l[x] , no other assumptions are made about k and l, then what would the roots in K look like, what would the roots in L look like, are there anything we can say about them?

Comment: if for example $k=K=\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ and $l=\mathbb{R}$ and $L=\mathbb{C}$ You get two factorizations $x^2+1=(x+1)(x+1)$ and $(x+i)(x-i)$, which would give a negative answer to Your question, if You start from the same base field $k=l$, for example if they are prime fields of the same characteristic the roots are the same up to isomorphisms

Comment: That's an illuminating example, thanks Peter!